# Is it possible debugging on iPhone connected to Windows?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am using VS2015 to develop app for iOS. I am able to do debugging on iPhone when it is connected to Mac that is used like build host. But I am interested if it is possible to do the debugging on an iPhone when it is connected to a Windows machine, NOT to Mac, and Mac to use just for building? If it is possible, what should be set in VS2015 to make that possible?

Comment: iOS devices must be "connected" to the Mac for debugging via USB or Wifi. Personally I find the Wifi option to slow to be productive, but you might feel it is acceptable....  I've used USB<->Ethernet dongles to extend Mac Pro (VMs) to dev desktops.... There are software-based USB redirectors that work but they "violate" the Apple ToS plus they are quite expensive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Xamarin docs](http://Xamarin.iOS%20for%20Visual%20Studio%20accomplishes%20an%20amazing%20feat:%20it%20lets%20developers%20create,%20build,%20and%20debug%20iOS%20applications%20on%20a%20Windows%20computer%20using%20the%20Visual%20Studio%20IDE.%20It%20cannot%20do%20this%20alone%20%E2%80%93%20iOS%20applications%20cannot%20be%20created%20without%20Apple%E2%80%99s%20compiler,%20and%20they%20cannot%20be%20deployed%20without%20Apple%E2%80%99s%20certificates%20and%20code-signing%20tools.%20This%20means%20that%20your%20Xamarin.iOS%20for%20Visual%20Studio%20installation%20requires%20a%20connection%20to%20a%20networked%20Mac%20OS%20X%20computer%20(which%20is%20refered%20to%20as%20the%20host%20or%20build%20host)%20to%20perform%20these%20tasks%20for%20you.%20Once%20configured,%20Xamarin%E2%80%99s%20tools%20will%20make%20the%20process%20as%20seamless%20as%20possible.):

> Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio accomplishes an amazing feat: it lets
>   developers create, build, and debug iOS applications on a Windows
>   computer using the Visual Studio IDE. It cannot do this alone – iOS
>   applications cannot be created without Apple’s compiler, and they
>   cannot be deployed without Apple’s certificates and code-signing
>   tools. This means that your Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio installation
>   requires a connection to a networked Mac OS X computer (which is
>   refered to as the host or build host) to perform these tasks for you.
>   Once configured, Xamarin’s tools will make the process as seamless as
>   possible.

So right now this is not possibile due to Apple limitations: only Mac can deploy on a iOS device because of certificates and codesign.

Comment: While this is true, this doesn't answer the question. Xamarin demoed USB remoting which is not available yet but is what the question is about.